# (MYSQL) Select the total of correct answer

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables,

Table **QUESTIONS** have ID, QUESTION, CORRECT_ANSWER_ID

Table **ANSWERS** have ID, QUESTION_ID, ANSWER_ID

i need to take the total of correct answer where ANSWER_ID must be same with CORRECT_ANSWER_ID, how to do that?

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: And add the code that you tried to use to get the correct results.  (see: [How do I ask a question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that your tables are structured somewhat like this:

Questions:

| ID (int) | Question (varchar) | Correct Answer ID (int) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Question Text 1 | 2 |
| 2 | Question Text 2 | 1 |

Answers:

| ID (int) | Question ID (int) | Answer ID (int) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |

If this is the case, then if we wanted to select the correct answer for question 1, we would want ID 2 from the Answers table, since it has an Answer ID of 2 and that corresponds to the correct answer ID from the Question table.

The following query should suffice:

```
select Questions.Question, Answers.AnswerID, Answers.ID
from Questions INNER JOIN Answers on Questions.ID = Answers.QuestionID
where Question.Correct_Answer_ID = Answer.AnswerID
```

If you then wanted the count of correct answers, simply use a `COUNT()` function in the above query:

```
select COUNT(*) from 
Questions INNER JOIN Answers on Questions.ID = Answers.QuestionID
where Question.Correct_Answer_ID = Answer.AnswerID
```